# Экспорт товаров из 1С и импорт их в базу интернет-магазина на django

Tags: django, postgresql, 1с

Экспорт осуществляется в XML файлы. Получается приличная папочка мегабайт на 300 вместе с картинками. Я написал скрипт  в 500 строк кода, который однократно парсит все это в объекты python и грузит в базу. Объекты парсятся в словари, затем методом Model.objects.bulk_create(obj_list) без вызова save для каждого объекта. Парсятся сразу несколько моделей в порядке их зависимости друг от друга. 
И все вроде работает. Но меня терзают смутные сомнения. Оптимальный ли это путь?
Ответственное лицо заявило, что будет делать мне выгрузку каждый день. В то же время, выгрузка такого объема явно избыточная. Изменений даже за день там в сотни раз меньше самой выгрузки. Меняются в основном остатки, то есть цифирь. Правильнее было бы отслеживать лишь эти изменения. Не так ли?
Какие существуют методы или решения экспорта-импорта из 1С для сайта на django?

Comment: После того как выгрузка из 1С сформирована, предлагаю обработать её и привести к виду Код, Хэш-сумма; Перед загрузкой пробегаем по новой таблице и сравниваем Хэш-сумму по Коду, с той что сейчас хранится в базе; Так определим изменившиеся позиции, - их и будем грузить ...

Comment: Хм. Такой вариант не избавляет нас от ежедневной БОЛЬШОЙ выгрузки-загрузки. Я ищу способа избежать ее. Но не понимаю, возможно ли это. Может быть это дело программистов 1С? Существует протокол oData, например. Или еще чего-то, чего я не знаю.

Comment: Чтобы избежать большой выгрузки, программист 1С может включить наш алгоритм (с Хэш-суммами) в процедуру формирования файла выгрузки. Но это потребует времени, и изменения конфигурации (на что не все пойдут)

Comment: Идеальный вариант - через собственное API. Написать API, и всю заботу о наполнении базы переложить на программера 1с.

Comment: @ЮрийСтрашко вариант с API хорош тем, что 1С ближе что и когда менялось. Программист 1С может у себя сделать например поле о изменении объекта N. Раз в сутки проходиться по этим изменениям и обновлять на сервере с django нужные объекты через API. Кстати никто не мешает ему это делать даже в реальном времени без всяких полей (зависит от постановки задачи и необходимости).

Answer (score -1):

Повесьте выгружаемые объекты на План обмена в 1С. При ежедневной выгрузке стучитесь в него и получаете только измененные объекты. После чего очищаете узел плана обмена, чтобы в следующий раз повторно их не тянуть